# Checking if a table is empty or not

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am making a vb.net project. In one form, I want it to work like if user presses a button it first checks if a table(Built with SQL Server) is empty or not. If it is empty it will open another form otherwise Resume functioning. How to check if the table is empty or not.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a SQL query to find the row count of your required table and then based on that count you can apply your logic by using conditional commands like `If[...]Else`:

```
Dim count As Int16
con.open()
query = "select count(*) from requiredTable"
cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
count = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
con.Close()
```

Comment: is it necessary to declare count before opening the connection

Comment: No you can declare it after opening a connection too.

Answer (score 5):

If you are after a sql statement that are check if there any rows in a table. THen you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    (
       CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM yourTable)
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END
    ) AS isEmpty
```

Comment: Thanks Arion. Will try it out. The above function is returning 0 for empty table?

Comment: @Niloy : No, it is return 1 if the table is empty

Comment: @Fred : No. Because there is a revert condition on the exists. So basically if it has not rows: 1 else 0

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

```
SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM MyTable
```

and in your vb code check the number of rows returned ( 0 rows =  table is empty)

Answer (score 0):

A Bit late, but for all people googled the same:

Slow Version:

```
select distinct 1 from MyTable ;
select count(*) from MyTable ;
```

Fast Version:

```
select count(*) from (select 1) where exists (select * from MyTable);
```

Maybe different products may have different results